# How can I enforce privacy on State variables in a Flux Store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getter-setter, flux, private-members

I have a small, home-brewed implementation of the Flux pattern that I'm working with, just to get a better understanding of the pattern.  Its working quite well, and I'm learning a ton!  But I've run into an issue I can't wrap my head around at the moment.  Apologies in advance if this has an obvious solution.

Imagine my simple Store called ExampleStore, and my simple Component ExampleComponent. In it there are:

```
_exampleState

getExampleState()

setExampleState()
```

in ExampleComponent, to stay updated:

```
_onChange: function() {
    setState({exampleState: ExampleStore.getExampleState()})
}
```

in ExampleStore, after a dispatched action I use the setter:

```
setExampleState(newStateFromDispatchedAction);
```

This works perfectly.  The data is flowing as it should. But I have a question, because it seems easy to break the pattern because there is no privacy enforced on my _exampleState within my Store. Since I have a getter and private setter method for _exampleState, it seems natural to me that somehow I want to enforce more privacy on the variable. Is there a nifty way to do this, that I am overlooking?

As it is now, if, for example, inside ExampleComponent I do (which I wouldn't, but I could):

```
this.state.exampleState = {field:'example'}
//doing this
this.state.exampleState.field = 'example2';
//changes the store _exampleState to {field:'example2'}
```

I have changed the value of _exampleState within ExampleStore directly, without making use of the setter. This seems dangerous (and makes me question why I'd have a private setter/public getter to begin with). This question comes after dealing with a pesky bug where a library I was using modified the state variable directly, and thereby within the Store.

Is there some good way I'm overlooking to enforce privacy on the state variables in my Store, so that they may not be changed directly through their references in ExampleComponent? Sorry if this is a dumb question and I'm overlooking something simple, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that one of the basic principles of the Flux philosophy is that **stores should have no (public) setters**. That means you should not be able to modify the store's state if not inside the store itself.

One way of enforcing the privacy could be by keeping state variables as private, only letting the store managing them.

**EDIT:** to "enforce" privacy, you could also return a deep copy of your state, as it is shown in the code.

The following code, based on the [official flux GitHub repository's flux-todomvc example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js), highlights the idea:

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var assign = require('object-assign');

// This is a private state variable that can only be accessed in this file
var _exampleState = {/*...*/};

var ExampleStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    EXAMPLE_STATE_CHANGED: 'EXAMPLE_STATE_CHANGED',
    // return a deep copy of your state so there is no way 
    // to modify the store's state by reference
    getExampleState: function() {
        return deepCopy(_exampleState);
    }

    /*...*/
};

// this is a private method (setter)
var _setExampleState = function(newExampleState) {
    _exampleState = newExampleState;
};

ExampleStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
    switch(action.actionType) {
        case AppConstants.CHANGE_EXAMPLE_STATE:
            _setExampleState(action.newExampleState);

            ExampleStore.emit(ExampleStore.EXAMPLE_STATE_CHANGED);

            break;
    }
});

// the implementation of deepCopy is a developer's choice
// this version of it is very inefficient
var deepCopy = function(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

module.exports = ExampleStore;
```

Facebook official examples are a good way to understand how to implement the core Flux concepts.

**EDIT:** this is a way of "enforcing" privacy of a state variable, but it is discouraged due to the clear loss of efficiency. I guess that the main idea here is that, even though you are able to do so in some situations, changing the store's state through reference is just against Flux. It is important to notice that this enforcement is not a reality in many big libraries. In React, for instance, it is possible to modify the state of a component directly, even though that is completely not recommended.

Comment: I do understand the Flux core concepts, and your example is exactly how mine is setup.  I get closure and scope, so theres no Store._exampleState. I understand that Flux has no public setters for its stores.

Now, do this.setState({exampleState: ExampleStore.getExampleState()}), in a Component. Now this.state.exampleState within that component carries a reference to _exampleState in your store.  Javascript is naturally carrying the reference and my client can now change that "private variable".  Its not safe, because any time I use my getter, now I have a defacto setter by reference?

Comment: That's definitely a good point! I would say then that you could follow a pattern such that your getters always return deep copy of your state object and not the reference to your real one. It turns out that there is no standard way of deep copying objects in JavaScript, so it is really a developer's choice. I will add an EDIT to my solution then.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your store in a [closure](http://lupomontero.com/using-javascript-closures-to-create-private-scopes/), and provide getters and setters, to prevent accidental modification of your state.

Comment: My store is wrapped in a closure, are you sure this can solve my problem in the context of how I'm using the Flux pattern?  I am pretty familiar with using closures/getters/setters within javascript.  In my case,  a component external to the store, receives references to the store's closure'd variables through a getter.  Now if I modify the variables containing references to the variables within the closure's scope (without the use of a setter), the variables within the closure's scope still seem to update?  I'll do more experimenting, maybe I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js (or Mori or seamless-immutable) provides the means to prevent modifications to nested data, while avoiding the need to make defensive deep clones in your getExampleState method. However, it has a huge impact on your coding style and code base. It possibly works best with a functional coding style, as is encouraged by some flux implementations, like https://github.com/rackt/redux.

Another option is to make it clearer that you don't want the state to be modified by ensuring that non-library code only sees the store state in React 'props', rather than React 'state' - not modifying props should be second nature to a React developer anyway (other bugs will occur if they modify it). This can be done using a generic flux wrapper component, such as Facebook's 'Container' - https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html